# Accessing Resources in a C# WPF Application (Same Assembly)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

(Before I jump into the nitty-gritty, I want to set the context:  I'm trying to load a WPF frame with the contents of an .html file that I'm including in my project as a resource.)

I create a new WPF Application; I add a new folder called 'foofiles' to the project, and I add a couple of files (page1.foo and page2.foo) to that folder.

For each newly added .foo file, I right-click on it, go to "Properties," and set the Build Action to 'Resource,' and the Copy To Output Directory to "Copy always."

I want to be able to access those files both in XAML:

```
<Frame x:Name="bar" Source="/foofiles/page1.foo"/>
```

And in procedural code:

```
private void someFunc()
{
    bar.Source = new Uri("/foofiles/page1.foo");
}
```

But I just can't figure out why this doesn't work -- I get a "Format of the URI could not be determined."

In the code-behind, I tried doing this:

```
private void someFunc()
{
    bar.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/foofiles/page1.foo");
}
```

which didn't throw an exception, but my main window crashed.

In my thinking, if I add a file of any type to my project, and if I mark it as "Resource" in "Build Action," I should be able to use that file per my examples above.  Also, I would like to use that file like this:

```
private void someOtherFunc()
{
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("/foofiles/page1.foo");
    string bar = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the *component*-part to your Pack URI like this

```
pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/ResourceName
```

where *AssemblyName* is the name of your assembly. So for your case, the following statement should work:

```
bar.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/foofiles/page1.foo");
```

More practically, try the relative pack uri notation:

```
bar.Source = new Uri("AssemblyName;component/foofiles/page1.foo", UriKind.Relative));
```

For stream reading resources use

```
var streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
using (var stream = streamResourceInfo.Stream)
{
   // do fancy stuff with stream
}
```

Comment: Also note that Pack Uris are WPF-specific, so _StreamReader_ is not aware of them.

Comment: Thanks for the response... your last code fragment showing how to stream read resources works like a charm!  (Unfortunately, both variants of crafting the Uri for use in loading Frame.Source both give a System.NotImplementedException in System.dll.  I just figured out how to break on CLR exceptions, however, and I'm gonna try to run that problem to ground.  Again, many thanks!

Comment: It turns out that my issue involved the context -- WPF doesn't allow you to load a frame.Source from an html file resource.  (You *can* do it using 'siteoforigin' but that means you're fetching the data from a file that's external to your assembly.)  Many thanks to you!

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't aware that WPF doesn't allow loading frame sources. Glad my response did help (at least partially).